# How to get Google Sitelinks on a website?

Tags: seo, google-search

There are a lot of websites that look professional in Google results. Try searching for 'stackoverflow' and you'll see at the top a result with a title, a description and a table of 8 links to stackoverflow categories. That's what I'm interested in producing for future websites.

So what must be done? Does it depend on the number of visitors? How long does it take until the results start looking like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [webmasters.se]. Stack Overflow is *not* for questions which are "How do I have [this effect] on how some third party site?" Once you've figured out *exactly* what you want to do (not the *effect* you want) Stack Overflow *may* (read the [on-topic page](/help/on-topic)) be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to "[sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)". Google generally does not make it public exactly how those are created (to prevent abuse, for example). I suspect you need the subpages to be very strongly linked, perhaps about the same amount or more than the top-level page. No way to know for sure. The best way to get your website looking good in Google is to make it as user-friendly and human-friendly as possible. I think Google typically looks for clues as to whether the website will be relevant to humans and very likely penalizes content that detracts from the interface just to become search-engine optimized.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure that each page (not just your home page) has a title.
2. Include description meta information, which search engines may (or may not) use for snippets to display.

Answer (score -2):

If an unordered list (*<ul><li><a href="http://..">Home...*) is used for navigation on the page, Google will pick that up and display it underneath the page listing when it is the #1 or #2 position listing.

Google may also use the description meta, or the first few lines of text that appear on the page, underneath the entry. It usually does this for searches in the other positions.