# Adding sublinks to google search results

Tags: google-search

I would like my sites to return Google Search results that look like this:

[image: Google Search Results for apple.com]

I suspect that ultimately it is up to Google what they display but is there any structured data I can add to my site to influence what they show?

Is a site map good enough?

How about just the structure of the HTML?

I posted this here because it is about code changes.  If this belongs on a different SO site just post a comment and I will move it to the appropriate site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Google Sitelinks on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565163/how-to-get-google-sitelinks-on-a-website)

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks